# Subset a matrix containing only Dates

Tags: r, date, subset

I got a matrix m which looks like this:

```
df <- c("2011-01-02", "2011-01-05", "2011-01-08", "2011-01-11", "2011-01-14", 
"2011-01-17", "2011-01-20", "2011-01-23", "2011-01-26", "2011-01-29", 
"2011-02-01", "2011-02-04", "2011-02-07", "2011-02-10", "2011-02-13") 

m <- matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = 15, byrow = T, data = df)
```

The entries within the matrix are `Date` class objects.

I have an interval with:

```
start <- as.Date("2011-01-26")
end <- as.Date("2011-02-10")
```

Now I want to select all the dates in matrix m that fall into this interval (e.g. cols 9 to 14) and output them into a new matrix. I was not able to perform this selection, any input is much appreciated! I use the `lubridate`package in R.

The formatting of the matrix m reflects a part of the 1st row of my original Dates matrix, which itself has `dim = (96, 850)`.

EDIT1: edited for clarity, the "start" & "end" were `Date` types but not labeled as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best to treat your dates as `Date` class

```
# convert to Dates
m <- as.Date(m)
start <- as.Date(start)
end <- as.Date(end)
```

Use `dplyr::between` to filter your data

```
require(dplyr)
ans <- m[dplyr::between(m, start, end)]  # m >= start && m <= end
# [1] "2011-01-26" "2011-01-29" "2011-02-01" "2011-02-04" "2011-02-07"
# [6] "2011-02-10"
```

This outputs a vector.

For a matrix output, try something like this

```
n <- m
n[!dplyr::between(n, start, end)] <- NA
newm <- matrix(nrow=1, ncol=15, byrow=T, data=n)
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately converting my original matrix m (with 96 rows and 850 cols) to `Date` class won't be possible cause it will not keep the structure of the matrix. I could try this for each row and then loop through it though...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R method using `seq` to generate the dates in between start and end and `%in%`

```
m[m %in% as.character(seq(as.Date(start), as.Date(end), by="day"))]
[1] "2011-01-26" "2011-01-29" "2011-02-01" "2011-02-04" "2011-02-07" "2011-02-10"
```

One thing to note is that Date is a class in R, as is matrix. It is quite difficult, (probably not impossible) to store dates in a matrix as Date objects. Instead, the above are stored as characters.

This solution converts start and end to Dates using `as.Date` and then uses `seq` to produce a vector of daily dates from start to end. These are then converted to characters and used to compare the element in m using `%in%`. Finally, `[` is used to extract the desired elements.